# Trying to get property of non-object on Laravel Middleware Role

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make middleware role for my authentication in my project, this is my middleware called sales.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Sales
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->user()->role == "sales"){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('error',"You don't have an access");
    }
}
```

and this is the route i protect from middleware

```
Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->middleware('sales')->name('dashboard');
```

and when i try to access dashboard to make sure my route is protected by middleware, it shows error like this

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

i appreciate if you answer this !

Comment: Show Your user model column

Comment: id,username,password,email,remember_token,role,created_at,updated_at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class Sales
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::User()->role=='sales'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('error',"You don't have an access");
    }
}
```